# Google App Engine plugin on Eclipse luna running on mac os x

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

Hey guys I have successfully downloaded and installed the google app engine plugin at Eclipse -> Help -> install new software according to this site
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Installing_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse

But after installation I cannot find any App Engine Project from my Eclipse, Please teach me how to fix this error. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys I have figure out what cause this problem as the java version of my mac is not larger then 7

For those who don't know, you can check on the version on terminal typing

java -version
or
javac -version

I keep this post for those who likes me fall into a simple stupid question.

Comment: I have the same problem, You change just java version on eclipse ?